# How to get a "ribbon" UI component, like in Office 2007, in a Java program?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, ribbon

I want to create a ribbon-based GUI. I am pretty much a newbie when it comes to Java interfaces, I have used the basic Swing toolkit, but that's it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction regarding what to do to get more flexibility with my UI and in particular being able to create a "ribbon"?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use **[Flamingo](http://java.net/projects/flamingo/)** for the Ribbon and **[Substance](http://java.net/projects/substance/)** for the Office 2007 look.

Here's a small preview from [Pushing Pixels](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2008/12/28/reworking-office-blue-skin-for-substance-51.html):

[image]

*PS: Not directly related to your question, but if you are new to Java UI programming, make sure you don't miss out on [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).*

**Update 2013-11-05:** Unfortunately Substantial and its successors are not actively maintained at the moment, although in my experience they are complete and production ready.

The current code can be found at Github at [Insubstantial/insubstantial](https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial). (Where "Flamingo" has been integrated into the "Insubstantial" package)

Also there seems to be a relatively up-to-date version available as a Maven artefact. (See http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.insubstantial)

**Update 2018-09-17:**
It was reanimated in December 2016, there were Maintenance Updates since February 2017 and [now Flamingo is part of Project Radiance](https://www.pushing-pixels.org/2018/05/23/hello-radiance.html).

Comment: +1 was about to point to that direction myself

Comment: Great kick start, thnx for the links!

Comment: Insubstantial (http://shemnon.com/speling/2011/04/insubstantial-62-release.html) is better than Substance now, Substance was discontinued :)

Comment: @ChrisDennett I'm having trouble getting a copy of that to run. Is it anywhere else? Is it more up to date now?

Comment: @Pureferret: Added links to Github and Maven.