# GUI Framework for new Windows OSs

Tags: java, user-interface

Is there any swing like framework for the newer Windows OS's?  Vista and & 7 apps have a different menuing and taskbar thing going and was wondering if there is any GUI components to utilize this new application look for Java.

Comment: Are you referring to ribbons? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_%28computing%29

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a "ribbon" UI component, like in Office 2007, in a Java program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530363/how-to-get-a-ribbon-ui-component-like-in-office-2007-in-a-java-program)

Comment: I guess ribbons is what I'm referring to

Comment: the How to get a "ribbon" UI componet" has be going down what will hopefully be the right path.  Trying out https://flamingo.dev.java.net/

Comment: There's a historical snapshot of [Flamingo on github](https://github.com/kirillcool/flamingo). There is some maintenance being done on a fork of Flamingo called [Insubstantial also on github](https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial).

Answer (score 0):

Java provides a standard look and feel across all platforms, so unfortunately no...
You can only use the standard Swing API, and the classes provided in that
Apple provides extensions to Java, allowing you to access certain other kinds of buttons, but I don't think Microsoft does the same.

Comment: You're presuming that the person asking is limited to using nothing outside Swing, even if it's compatible. There exist additional UI libraries available for Java.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to replace the whole of Swing in order to get a new component. You can use the [Flamingo](http://flamingo.dev.java.net/) component suite to provide a ribbon.

Alternatively you may prefer SWT, which provides a more native look-and-feel in general (i.e. your application will look more like a "normal" Windows Vista/7 application). SWT also has a [third-party ribbon component](http://hexapixel.com/projects/ribbon).