# Changing the look of JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, ms-word, look-and-feel, jtabbedpane

[image: JTabbedPane]
[image: MS Ribbon]

I know fairly well how to use a `JTabbedPane` but it does not look like the tabs that you get in MS Word's ribbon . I want to know if there is a way to make the `JTabbedPane` look like the ribbon in MS Word (or any other way to change its looks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it depends on the look and feel. [Substance](http://java.net/projects/substance/) has the look and feel you want. You can have a complete open-source ribbon component as well, see this question:

[How to get a "ribbon" UI component, like in Office 2007, in a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530363/how-to-get-a-ribbon-ui-component-like-in-office-2007-in-a-java-program)

Note that [Insubstantial](https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial) is a fork of Substance that is actively maintained. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898028/what-happened-to-the-substance-laf

Comment: The top answer on the `How to get ribbon UI` suggested [Flamingo](http://java.net/projects/flamingo/downloads) but when I go there, there is nothing available for download.

Comment: You can get flamingo from insubstantial too, https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial/tree/master/flamingo